# Calculating TN,TP,FP,FN based on KNN predictions

Tags: pandas, knn, confusion-matrix

I'm building a KNN classifier to predict if some record is red/green. The model itself seems fine, but I'm having trouble calculating tn,fn,tp,fp within my for loop. Basically each loop through, I need to compare the ndarray pred_k ("y_hat") to the static ndarray Y_test ("y_actual.) Thoughts?

```
X = df [["f1","f2", "f3", "f4"]]. values
Y = df [["color"]]. values.ravel()

scaler = StandardScaler (). fit (X)
X = scaler . transform (X)

X_train ,X_test , Y_train , Y_test = train_test_split (X,Y, test_size =0.5 , random_state =0)
error_rate = []

for k in [3 , 5, 7, 9, 11]:
    knn_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier ( n_neighbors =k)
    knn_classifier . fit ( X_train , Y_train )
    pred_k = knn_classifier . predict ( X_test )
    error_rate . append (np. mean ( pred_k != Y_test ))
```

Comment: Check out [sklearn's confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sklearn's confusion matrix.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(Y_test, pred_k).ravel()
```